# Tabbing not working once popup is closed in WPF application

Tags: wpf, keyboard, popup, focus

I have a WPF application in which data is arranged as groups.

The structure of App is as follows

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                AboutButton HelpButton
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----H Button---------------grouped data-------------------------------------
-----H Button---------------grouped data-------------------------------------
-----H Button---------------grouped data-------------------------------------
-----H Button---------------grouped data-------------------------------------
-----H Button---------------grouped data-------------------------------------
                                                       Apply Changes button
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I didnt click the "H" button, the tabbing works seemlessly..that is -> AboutButton-> HelpButton-> { H  Button- grouped data }(go through all instances of these combincation-> Apply changes button -> AboutButton.

On click of H Button,About button, Help Button - a popup will be displayed.

If we click any of these buttons - popup displayed - close the popup, from that time onward the tabbing become confined to that particular group.

That is - If we click About/Help button - it will not move to the controls below it.
If we click the "H" button - the focus will not move to About/Help or Apply changes button

I need it to be seamless even if i click a button open a popup.

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: post the relevant XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue here is the base window is loosing the tab navigation info set to it.
I just added a key down event for the window..and set the tab navigation from code behind.